# ListView and TextView in same screen

Tags: android

In my application has two Activities.  One is main activity and other is activity for displaying menus.  I choose listview for displaying menu.  In app screen i planed to place listview in top and a textview in bottom.  The textview is displaying a status from main activity.  Is it possible ?

[image]

Comment: Can you provide a picture of what you want. I'm sure what you want is possible, but the picture would better explain it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible, but you you need to fix height of list on screen, like you can use RelativeLayout, and can set textview param to bottom of parent, and wrap content height, listview height to fill_parent, and above to textView.

Comment: shall i put specified content layout in main.xml or menulist.xml ?

Comment: yes, you need to put main.xml or menulist.xml, but as from your requirements it seems you want textview to use a footer, in overall application, in that case you can use fragments.

Comment: I want textview use as footer, is any link available, i am not aware about fragments.

Answer (score 0):

putting the TextView bellow the ListView can be done with a RelativeLayout or even a TableLayout,

You can pass data between the main activity and the menu activity through the Intent